# how to fix "Cannot find module './components/hello-world/hello-world.component'.ts(2307)"

Tags: node.js

How to solve this type of error

> "Cannot find module
>   './components/hello-world/hello-world.component'(2307)"

in node js?

Comment: please, add the code where you import this module

Comment: Please make sure that this component does exist.

Also by that naming convention, that's not a module but rather a component.